# chain promises in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise

I've created many promises like that, in order to create object in my database.

```
var createUserPromise = new Promise(
  function(resolve, reject) {
    User.create({
      email: 'toto@toto.com'
    }, function() {
      console.log("User populated"); // callback called when user is created
      resolve();
    });
  }
);
```

At the end, I want call all my promises in the order I want. (because somes object depend of other, so I need to keep that order)

```
createUserPromise
  .then(createCommentPromise
    .then(createGamePromise
      .then(createRoomPromise)));
```

So I expect to see :

```
User populated
Comment populated
Game populated
Room populated
```

Unfortunately, this messages are shuffled and I don't understand what.

Thanks

Comment: Note - mongoose already returns promises - your code should have `new Promise` exactly zero times.  Please see stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it and http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looks like you understood promises wrong, re-read some tutorials on promises and this [article](http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html).

As soon as you create a promise using `new Promise(executor)`, it is invoked right away, so all your function actually are executed as you create them and not when you chain them.

`createUser` actually should be a function returning a promise and not a promise itself. `createComment`, `createGame`, `createRoom` too.

Then you will be able to chain them like this:

```
createUser()
.then(createComment)
.then(createGame)
.then(createRoom)
```

Latest versions of [mongoose return promises](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html) if you don't pass callbacks, so you don't need to wrap it into a function returning a promise.

Comment: You were right, I did it wrong. I changed my code and everything goes right. I accept you answer because of the explanation. Thanks you

Comment: Just a little fix.... you forgot the parenthesis on `createUser`, since it is a function.

Answer (score 4):

You should wrap your Promises into functions. The way you're doing, they are called right away.

```
var createUserPromise = function() {
  return new Promise(
    function(resolve, reject) {
      User.create({
        email: 'toto@toto.com'
      }, function() {
        console.log("User populated"); // callback called when user is    created
        resolve();
      });
    }
  );
};
```

Now you can chain Promises, like this:

```
createUserPromise()
.then(createCommentPromise)
.then(createGamePromise)
.then(createRoomPromise);
```

Comment: This isn't chaining, take a look at this http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html