# Javascript - call two asynchronous functions sequentially

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have a code that looks something like this

```
class foo {
    constructor() {

        // calling a, b, c synchronously
        a().then(
            function(response) {
                b().then(
                    function(response) {
                        c();
                    }, function(error) {
                        // pass
                    }
                );
            }, function(error) {
                // pass
            }
        );
    }

    a() {
        return new Promise(function(fullfill, reject) {

            // x is any function that returns a promise, making the
            // implementation of this function "a" asynchronous
            x().then(
                function(response) {
                    fullfill(response);
                }, function(error) {
                    reject(error);
                }
            );

        });
    }

    b() {
        return new Promise(function(fullfill, reject) {

            // x is any function that returns a promise, making the
            // implementation of this function "b" asynchronous
            x().then(
                function(response) {
                    fullfill(response);
                }, function(error) {
                    reject(error);
                }
            );

        });
    }

    c() {
        // do something
    }

}
```

Basically, I have two functions `a` and `b` which are both asynchronous. 
These functions are asynchronous because they both call some function `x` which returns a promise (in my case, it is a query to a database).

I need to call `a`, followed by `b` followed by `c` but sequentially. One way of doing so is what I have implemented in the code above, but it results in nasty nested promise responses.

Is there any other way that I can achieve this same result, without using the following syntax (because if this is the only possible solution, then I might as well not use it at all).

Comment: use promise chaining http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34696696/chain-promises-in-javascript

Comment: @atmd Yes. `a`, `b` and `c` are functions that I have written. But they all make queries to a database and these queries are asynchronous. And I have no control over these queries.

Comment: What @m14 said, just do `a().then(b).then(c);`.

Comment: If `x()` has a `.then()` then it's already a promise. DO NOT create a promise yourself in this case, just do `a() {return x()}`. That's all. Only if `x()` does not return a promise (don't have a `.then()`) should you create a promise yourself.

Comment: BTW, synchronously !== sequentially. You cannot synchronise an asynchronous function; but you *can* call several asynchronous functions in sequence…

Comment: @slebetman Thanks. Didn't realise that :)

Answer (score 2):

Use promise chaining as shown below:

```
a().then(resA => {
    // resA is response of function a()
    // Do whatever you want with resA here
    // and then return promise of function b()

    return b();
})
.then(resB => {
    // resB is response of function b()
    // Do whatever you want with resA here
    // and then return promise of function c()

    return c();
})
.then(resC => {
    // resC is response of function c()
    // Do whatever you want with resC here
})
.catch(err => {
    // Handle any reject/error of functions a, b or c
});
```

If you want to carry the response of function a and b till the end then you can do the chaining as follows:

```
a().then(resA => {
    // resA is response of function a()
    // Do whatever you want with resA here
    // and then return promise of function b()

    return b().then(resB => { resA: resA, resB: resB });
})
.then(res => {
    // res is a object with rsponse of function a() & b()
    // res.resA is response of function a()
    // res.resB is response of function b()
    // Do whatever you want to with the responses here
    // then return promise of function c()

    return c().then(resC, { resA: res.resA, resB: res.resB, resC: resC });
})
.then(resC => {
    // res is a object with rsponse of function a(), b() & c()
    // res.resA is response of function a()
    // res.resB is response of function b()
    // res.resC is response of function c()
    // Do whatever you want to with the responses
})
.catch(err => {
    // Handle any reject/error of functions a, b or c
});
```

The above code is elaborate for demo/explanation. It can be reduced with ES6 as shown below

```
a().then(resA => {
    // resA is response of function a()
    // Do whatever you want with resA here
    // and then return promise of function b()

    return b().then(resB => { resA, resB });
})
.then(res => {
    // res is a object with rsponse of function a() & b()
    // res.resA is response of function a()
    // res.resB is response of function b()
    // Do whatever you want to with the responses here
    // then return promise of function c()

    return c().then(resC, Object,assign(res, { resC }));
})
.then(resC => {
    // res is a object with rsponse of function a(), b() & c()
    // res.resA is response of function a()
    // res.resB is response of function b()
    // res.resC is response of function c()
    // Do whatever you want to with the responses
})
.catch(err => {
    // Handle any reject/error of functions a, b or c
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Let seq = [f1,f2,...,fn] be a sequence of zero-argument promise
returning functions.  Build a promise p that will execute them
sequentially with fi invoked after f{i-1}.

var p = seq.reduce( 
         (p_acc,f) => p_acc.then( ()=>f() )
        )

Then you probably want to do

p.catch(...)