# Promise chaining, use result of request for another one

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I'm using ES6 within node.js. Long story short, I only now about callbacks and want to replace them with promises.

I made a test project to get an oauth2 token from an api/endpoint, refresh it and finally revoke it. The goal is, to give the response of the previous request to the next. My code looks like this:

```
const oauth2Adapter = require('./api/adapter/oauth2Adapter')

function test () {
oauth2Adapter.RequestNewAccessToken()
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response)
  return oauth2Adapter.RefreshAccessToken(response.body)
})
.then(function (response) {
  return oauth2Adapter.RevokeAccessToken(response.body)
})
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.log)
}

test()
```

The first promise returns it's response. The next step is now to give it to the second promise as a parameter. But the second promise only receives an undefined object.

I'm a second year cs apprentice, any critic helps me and is appreciated.

Edit: adding the 'return' keyword didn't change the situation. The problem is that 'RefreshAccessToken' 'undefined' receives. Also I don't know if this helps, but here is the 'oauth2Adapter.js' code:

```
const Promise = require('promise')
const rp = require('request-promise')
const credentials = require('../../misc/credentials/Staging')

function RequestNewAccessToken () {
  try {
    const response = rp({
      method: 'POST',
      url: `${credentials.baseUrl}/oauth/token`,
      form: {
        client_id: credentials.apiKey,
        client_secret: credentials.apiSecret,
        username: credentials.username,
        password: credentials.password,
        grant_type: credentials.grantType
      },
      json: true
    })
    return Promise.resolve(response)
  } catch (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error)
  }
}

function RefreshAccessToken (token) {
  try {
    const response = rp({
      method: 'POST',
      url: `${credentials.baseUrl}/oauth/token`,
      form: {
        client_id: credentials.apiKey,
        client_secret: credentials.apiSecret,
        grant_type: 'refresh_token',
        refresh_token: token.refresh_token
      },
      json: true
    })
    return Promise.resolve(response)
  } catch (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error)
  }
}

function RevokeAccessToken (token) {
  try {
    const response = rp({
      method: 'POST',
      url: `${credentials.baseUrl}/oauth/revoke`,
      form: {
        client_id: credentials.apiKey,
        client_secret: credentials.apiSecret,
        token: token.access_token
      },
      json: true
    })
    return Promise.resolve(response)
  } catch (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error)
  }
}

module.exports = { RequestNewAccessToken, RefreshAccessToken, RevokeAccessToken }
```

If I execute the code, i get the following text by stdout:

```
Debugger attached.

    { access_token: '31744bf03a2fb92edb67fcbeead14f4ed8c540843c2439179a54b6439dc94c0e',
      token_type: 'Bearer',
      expires_in: 660,
      refresh_token: 'e53642c69bd0ad954d886dad7a437f88c8c269ecacf2cdcfebc8af1a2d0d9b1e',
      created_at: 1538471914 }
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'refresh_token' of undefined
        at Object.RefreshAccessToken (/Users/quest1onmark/coding_stuff/nodejs/EdgeDeviceAdministration/api/adapter/oauth2Adapter.js:28:28)
        at /Users/quest1onmark/coding_stuff/nodejs/EdgeDeviceAdministration/Main.js:7:28
        at tryCatcher (/Users/quest1onmark/coding_stuff/nodejs/EdgeDeviceAdministration/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
        at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/quest1onmark/coding_stuff/nodejs/EdgeDeviceAdministration/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
        at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/quest1onmark/coding_stuff/nodejs/EdgeDeviceAdministration/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
        at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/quest1onmark/coding_stuff/nodejs/EdgeDeviceAdministration/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
        at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/quest1onmark/coding_stuff/nodejs/EdgeDeviceAdministration/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:694:18)
        at _drainQueueStep (/Users/quest1onmark/coding_stuff/nodejs/EdgeDeviceAdministration/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
        at _drainQueue (/Users/quest1onmark/coding_stuff/nodejs/EdgeDeviceAdministration/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
        at Async._drainQueues (/Users/quest1onmark/coding_stuff/nodejs/EdgeDeviceAdministration/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
        at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/Users/quest1onmark/coding_stuff/nodejs/EdgeDeviceAdministration/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
        at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
        at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)
        at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:745:5)
    Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...

    Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [chain promises in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34696696/chain-promises-in-javascript)

Comment: I've read [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34696696/chain-promises-in-javascript) completely and it doesn't describe my problem, as I used promises correctly, as far as I now and other users have reported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second code block is not using promises at all well

try the following instead

```
const Promise = require('promise')
const rp = require('request-promise')
const credentials = require('../../misc/credentials/Staging')

function RequestNewAccessToken () {
    return rp({
      method: 'POST',
      url: `${credentials.baseUrl}/oauth/token`,
      form: {
        client_id: credentials.apiKey,
        client_secret: credentials.apiSecret,
        username: credentials.username,
        password: credentials.password,
        grant_type: credentials.grantType
      },
      json: true
    });
}

function RefreshAccessToken (token) {
    return rp({
      method: 'POST',
      url: `${credentials.baseUrl}/oauth/token`,
      form: {
        client_id: credentials.apiKey,
        client_secret: credentials.apiSecret,
        grant_type: 'refresh_token',
        refresh_token: token.refresh_token
      },
      json: true
    });
}

function RevokeAccessToken (token) {
    return rp({
      method: 'POST',
      url: `${credentials.baseUrl}/oauth/revoke`,
      form: {
        client_id: credentials.apiKey,
        client_secret: credentials.apiSecret,
        token: token.access_token
      },
      json: true
    });
}

module.exports = { RequestNewAccessToken, RefreshAccessToken, RevokeAccessToken }
```

As for your code that USES this - you `console.log(response)` which has the required format, but then you `oauth2Adapter.RefreshAccessToken(response.body)` ... response has no body!

So, simply do:

```
const oauth2Adapter = require('./api/adapter/oauth2Adapter')
function test () {
    return oauth2Adapter.RequestNewAccessToken()
    .then(response => oauth2Adapter.RefreshAccessToken(response))
    .then(response => oauth2Adapter.RevokeAccessToken(response))
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.log)
}
test()
```

but, since you pass `response` straight to the next function without any processing, you can also do

```
const oauth2Adapter = require('./api/adapter/oauth2Adapter')
function test () {
    return oauth2Adapter.RequestNewAccessToken()
    .then(oauth2Adapter.RefreshAccessToken)
    .then(oauth2Adapter.RevokeAccessToken)
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.log)
}
test()
```

Comment: RefreshAccesToken still receives 'undefined'. I've added the error message. Thank you for your help.

Comment: well of course it does - the code I didn't fix calls `return oauth2Adapter.RefreshAccessToken()` ... no argument ... what shoul;d the argument be?

Comment: was a typo, in my code it looks like this    return oauth2Adapter.RefreshAccessToken(response.body)

Comment: OK, so are you saying that you still get undefined? even when passing response.body? that means response.body is undefined ... and that's not something I can fix because have no idea what you are getting in your requests

Comment: I've shown what I get back in the third code block. Just above the error message. I really don't get what I'm doing wrong and I feel like I'm wasting your and the other's time.

Comment: well ... you `console.log(response)` and then you `return oauth2Adapter.RefreshAccessToken(response.body)` ... see the issue :p

Answer (score 1):

Promises are chained by returning another Promise at the end of the `then` block. It looks like you didn't call `return` properly in the first `then` block. You should correct that as follows:

```
oauth2Adapter.RequestNewAccessToken()
.then(function (requestReponse) {
  console.log(response)
  return oauth2Adapter.RefreshAccessToken()
})
.then(function (refreshResponse) {
  return oauth2Adapter.RevokeAccessToken(JSON.parse(refreshResponse.body))
})
```

As a sidenote, I like to name my callback args differently with each Promise return, which will help to keep things clean!

Comment: I've added the 'return' keyword where it is supposed to be, but nothing has changed. Could you take a look at the edit I made and tell me if I understood something wrong? Would help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Promises should be properly *chained*. This means that `then` and `catch` callbacks should return a promise to chain, in case there's one.

Also, `response` parameter is parsed response body when `json: true` is used. If a server responds with token object, then it should be passed as an argument to the function that expects it:

```
...
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response)
  return oauth2Adapter.RefreshAccessToken(response)
})
...
```

Comment: I've added the 'return' keyword where it is supposed to be, but nothing has changed. Could you take a look at the edit I made and tell me if I understood something wrong? Would help me a lot.

Comment: you're still missing the return at `oauth2Adapter.RefreshAccessToken()` @JonasRaphaelSchultheiss

Comment: @JonasRaphaelSchultheiss I see no problem except that you use try..catch, Promise.resolve and Promise.reject which aren't needed there (they shouldn't cause a problem). It could be just `return rp(...)`. It seems unlikely that fixed code exposes the same behaviour as the mistake. I'd suggest to double check that you're running the code that was fixed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I execute the right code. I'll do a quick restart (even if i don't expect it to work after that it's the thought that counts). I've added the error message in the question, but I don't think that it helps. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @JonasRaphaelSchultheiss I see. I misunderstood what *The problem is that 'RefreshAccessToken' 'undefined' receives* could mean. You're not passing an argument to `RefreshAccessToken()`, while it expects a token. Btw, you don't need JSON.parse when you use json: true. It's either one or another.

Comment: @JonasRaphaelSchultheiss You also don't need `response.body` with `json: true`. It's already parsed body this way. You can check what `response` is in your case and proceed from there.